# Tensorflow object detection train own dataset

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to train an object detection model for my AI studies,

Below error is raised while running  below code in conda cmd

```
python train.py --logtostdrr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline=_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_pets.config
```

> File
>   "..\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg\object_detection\data_decoders\tf_example_decoder.py",
>   line 29, in 
>       from object_detection.protos import input_reader_pb2 ImportError: cannot import name 'input_reader_pb2'

Answer (score 0):

The pb2 files are generated after running the `protoc` command. From the `models/research` directory run the following command:

```sh
protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
```

Then, install the research and slim modules, then update your `PYTHONPATH` variable:

```sh
python setup.py install 
cd slim && python setup.py install 
# Change /path/to/models to your path to models project
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/models
```

After those steps, you should be able to run your script.